# draw a graph according to battery level data from android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have been developing an app to show battery information. I have taken whatever possible info form batterymanager, and now what I want to do is to draw a graph according to the battery level against the time. for this, my concept is to monitor the battery level using an alammanager object bt I dont think it would work! please can any one help me with a good concept!

Comment: Have u tried out your approach ?? for drawing graphs you can use http://www.achartengine.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For display a graph first you will have to listen the battery level and then save each better status with date and time in your database. For more information about battery monitoring you can follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html)

After that you can use [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/) for create a graph in android. Use the database value to display graph.

Comment: Is it the database necessary?

Comment: @David_D Database is needed to read old values of the battery so that we can get the battery value at the particular time and based on that we can display graph. You can use any data storage to save old values.

Comment: But is possible display for example only 48hours without database and then clear all? In my case isn't necessary save the values. Have you ever draw this kind of graphs?